# Adding Data Manually to Correlate with Refreshing Rows of Existing Live Data Connection Feed in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table in Excel that is populated by a live connection to an external database.  The SQL used to generate this table and refresh it looks similar to this (only with more fields and such):

```
SELECT DISTINCT shr_pf_student_v.ID,   

FROM shr_pf_student_v
```

What my customer wants to be able to do is add additional columns and manually add data that correlates to the ID in each row in Excel.  Of course, when the ID data is refreshed, if new rows are added or deleted, the manually added data no longer correlates with the ID it was originally intended to match up with.

I've thoroughly explored the Excel Connection "External Data Properties" options and none solve this issue.  I've only found this one solution here:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/376984-database-query-possibilities.html but after several hours of attempted application, I can't get it to work and I'm not sure that it's possible to do this way either.

Lookup formulas won't work of course because as soon as the data is refreshed, the data looks just like the new refreshed set.

Any new viable options are welcomed.  I've searched high and low but I can't help but think that this is such a valuable process that must be rather prevalent and have a solution developed for it somewhere out there?

Many thanks,

Lindsay

Comment: Best would be to write back the changes to the SQL. If that's not an option then you have - in my opinion - two options (1) create a separate sheet where the user enters the IDs (manually) and all the additional data and combine this sheet with the SQL sheet on a new sheet using `VLookUps` or (2) write a few VBA macros (depending how convenient you want to make it) which "saves" your changes on a separate (possibly hidden) sheet in the background before making a refresh from the SQL and then get the "saved" data back again. My preference: write back to SQL or (alternatively) the VBA route.

Comment: I have been trying to write back the changes to the SQL but I have not been able to manage it.  The SQL for the EXCEL table query is very different from normal SQL.  It looks like this:  SELECT `'PF Data$'`.alternate_id, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 1`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 1 Amt`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 2`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 2 Amt`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 3`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 3 Amt`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 4`, `'PF Data$'`.`Source 4 Amt`
FROM `'PF Data$'` `'PF Data$'` and when I try to incorporate that with the normal SQL that I reference in my question, it is rejected.

Comment: I assume this is because the connection string associated with the live data feed is pointing to the outside database.

Comment: If I could incorporate the SQL for the table query, I am also having a difficult time conceptualizing how the original table with manual data entry columns could be overwritten using the SQL, but I've never done anything remotely like this before.